# multiple titles for the same person?

Tags: word-usage

If I want to talk about one person with multiple titles, for instance:
"Jimin Park is an assistant professor and a singer."
"Jimin Park is an assistant professor and singer."

Do I need (a) for the second title ("singer")?

Comment: “assistant professor” and “singer” are not titles, they are just descriptions.

Comment: Titles are honorifics that are connected with the name, as in "Doctor Park", "Sir Patrick Stewart", ior "James Jones, Ph.D."

Comment: It's more idiomatic to "delete" the second occurrence of the article in such contexts IF the two nouns are a reasonably "natural" pairing: *(**an** actor **and singer**).* It's far less idiomatic to delete the repeated article if the second noun *isn't* something that's naturally associated with the first. In that situation we'd normally keep both articles: *He was a jobbing actor and **a** lay preacher until he lost his voice*.

Comment: perfect explain by @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to repeat the article ("a" and "an" are the same word, only spelled slightly differently in different phonetic contexts).  I can find examples of a more common combination "actor and singer" for example

> Gene Kelly was an actor and singer for most of his career. ([source](https://gmatclub.com/forum/an-actor-and-singer-for-most-of-his-career-gene-kelly-expanded-his-st-383224.html))

While it isn't necessary to repeat the article, it is permitted:

> According to Beales' online profiles, she was an actor and a singer...([source](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/may/30/bethany-maria-beales-death-murder-investigation-launched-city-of-london))

Comment: I think I would include the 'a' in the OP's example, as 'singer' is such a different kind of occupation from 'professor' (unless they are a professor of music!) - _and [he/she is also] a singer_.

Comment: Was Ringo an 'assistant singer'?

Comment: @M - It took me a while to figure that one out. You mean that, without the second article, _assistant_ could be understood as applying to both occupations?

Comment: It took me awhile to work that out too!  English is ubiquitously ambiguous, so, the fact that the "no article" version, can be ambiguous - is irrelevant.

Comment: @KateBunting - consider 'head cook and bottle-washer'.

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, that is exactly what I meant.